# flutter hand detection

Tags: flutter, ar

Сел за изучение flutter'a,
захотелось попробовать ar технологии.
Хочу попробовать обнаруживать руки попадающие в камеру!
Подскажите кто чем может куда смотреть с чего начать,
как это работает! потратил день на поиски ничего пока не нашел

Answer (score 0):

Flutter не очень подходит для AR, лучше используйте unity. А потом встройте ее в приложение через [flutter_unity_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget). Вот статья как это можно сделать: [Flutter + Unity3D AR Foundation.](https://morioh.com/p/df41a2ee57b7)